# Implementing a multimethod in separate files in different namespace

Tags: clojure, polymorphism, multimethod

I am trying to define a multimethod and its implementation in a separate file. It goes something like this:
In file 1

```
(ns thing.a.b)
(defn dispatch-fn [x] x)
(defmulti foo dispatch-fn)
```

In file 2

```
(ns thing.a.b.c
  (:require [thing.a.b :refer [foo]])
(defmethod foo "hello" [s] s)
(defmethod foo "goodbye" [s] "TATA")
```

And in the main file when I am calling the method I define something like this:

```
(ns thing.a.e
  (:require thing.a.b :as test))
.
.
.
(test/foo "hello")
```

When I do this I get an exception saying `"No method in multimethod 'foo'for dispatch value: hello`

What am I doing wrong? Or is it not possible to define implementations of multimethods in separate files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible. The problem is because `thing.a.b.c` namespace isn't loaded. You have to load it before using.

This is a correct example:

```
(ns thing.a.e
  (:require
    [thing.a.b.c] ; Here all your defmethods loaded
    [thing.a.b :as test]))

(test/foo "hello")
```